# Can I create a link to another page using ScrollSpy in bootstrap, while also keeping default functionality?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a site that is using bootstrap and ScrollSpy nav to scroll to sections of the page. It all works perfect, however, I want to add a link in my nav to another page on my site. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include anchors on your other page and then add a data-target.  For example:

```
<a href="sample.html#foo" data-target="#foo">Sample</a>
```

Comment: There's nothing precluding you from adding the anchor/id to the top of your other page.

Comment: So I am on page index.php with anchor links to #section-1, #section-2, #section-3, #section-4, #section-5 now I want to add a link to user.php. How would I set that up. I did as you stated above but it didn't work.

Also, the anchor is on user.php already.